# Java jOOQ issue when trying to update a table using a POJO Record

Tags: java, h2, jooq

I'm trying to execute a simple updateRecord function, but it is giving me an error that I can't find the cause or any other people having it.

An example test project can be found at:
https://github.com/billbarni/jooq-studer-h2-test

Java code:

```
import static mypackage.database.model.h2.public_.Tables.EXPRESSAO;
import mypackage.database.model.h2.public_.tables.pojos.Expressao;
import mypackage.database.model.h2.public_.tables.records.ExpressaoRecord;

public void updateQuery(Expressao expressaoPojo) {
  ExpressaoRecord expressaoRecord = ctx.newRecord(EXPRESSAO, expressaoPojo);
  ctx.executeUpdate(expressaoRecord); // Error with this parameter
}
```

Database create expression:

```
CREATE TABLE
 expressao (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  conteudo VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  qtd_tempo INT NOT NULL,
  tipo_tempo VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  data_inicial TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
 );
```

Gradle generator configs:

```
plugins {
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '2.0.9'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-codegen', version: '3.10.4'
    jooqRuntime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.197'
}

jooq {
    h2(sourceSets.main) {
        jdbc {
            driver = 'org.h2.Driver'
            url = 'jdbc:h2:file:./db'
            user = 'sa'
            password = ''
        }
        generator {
            name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator'
            strategy {
                name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
            }
            database {
                name = 'org.jooq.util.h2.H2Database'
            }
            generate {
                relations = true
                deprecated = false
                records = true
                immutablePojos = true
                fluentSetters = true
            }
            target {
                packageName = 'mypackage.database.model.h2'
                directory = 'src/main/java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java gives me this error before compiling:

> executeUpdate (R) in DSLContext cannot be applied to
>   (mypackage.database.model.h2.public_.tables.records.ExpressaoRecord)  
>   reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that
>   ExpressaoRecord conforms to UpdatableRecord

What is the reason behind this issue? What am I doing wrong?

Obs.: I have 2 databases (firebird and h2) and I use jOOQ generator from Gradle to generate pojos and other classes automatically. They are not sharing POJOs or anything complex. The project is VERY small and simple.

Obs 2.: I used several versions of jOOQ libraries (from 3.9 to the new 3.11) and the problem persists.

Lukas Eder, god of jOOQ, I await for your return to save me from this verbose slumber.

Comment: Here I am to relieve you from your pains. Can you post the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) of your `EXPRESSAO` table?

Comment: For the record, this issue has also been reported to the gradle-jooq-plugin: https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/73

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the [nu.studer.jooq](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin) plugin, since when using another code generator the H2 database model classes that reflect tables with primary keys recieves the UpdatableTable extension/implementation.

I opened an issue on the plugin, for those who want to follow it, you can check the open issues in the plugin github page already linked a few lines above.

The new releases of the plugin (versions 3.x+) seem to have fixed the issue. Be careful when upgrading, since there are many breaking changes in the plugin config and it forces the usage of the new jOOQ version (3.11+) also.

Answer (score 0):

[`DSLContext.executeUpdate(R)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#executeUpdate-R-) requires `R` to be a subtype of [`UpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html), which makes sense. Only a record that is "updatable" (i.e. knows its primary key) can effectively be updated.

It appears that your `ExpressaoRecord` is not an `UpdatableRecord`, but just a [`TableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableRecord.html). This can have several reasons:

#### You deactivated the `<relations/>` flag in the code generator

`<relations>false</relations>` can be used to turn off the generation of all relationship related features, including primary key, foreign key information. Without this information, you effectively cannot generate `UpdatableRecord` types.

#### Your table doesn't have a primary key.

Without a primary key, the code generator doesn't generate an `UpdatableRecord`.

You can either add a primary key to your table, or tell the code generator about a "synthetic primary key":

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-primary-keys/

Or, you can "override" your primary key by treating any unique key as the primary key:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-override-primary-keys/

Comment: Sorry I took so long to update my question. The CREATE of my table is included now. Maybe I should use other sintax then? H2 accepted that one but is doing something wrong in the column flags?

Comment: @MBarni: OK, so hypothesis #1 has not been confirmed. Can you post your code generation configuration?

Comment: Question updated with gradle config. I'm using a third party plugin, maybe it is causing the issue?

Comment: @MBarni: That would be a very significant issue in that third party plugin, you wouldn't be the only one suffering from it, so I'd exclude that as a possible reason. Also, your config looks correct. Just checking one more thing: does your `ExpressaoRecord` extends `UpdatableRecordImpl`? Does the problem persist if you remove your `includes` specification?

Comment: `ExpressaoRecord extends TableRecordImpl<ExpressaoRecord>`. Removed the `includes` from the Gradle config, so it generates all tables (there is only one anyway) and the problem persists. `ExpressaoRecord` still does not extend `UpdatableRecordImpl`.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect current config as you pointed - removed includes, changed H2 create table expression to be more verbose, updated dependencies. And yes, I removed all generated classes, removed and rebuilt the database and generated everything once again.

Comment: @MBarni: That's really weird. I'll try to reproduce this tomorrow. Perhaps it is an issue in the third party plugin after all...

Comment: Ok. Thanks A LOT. You are an awesome person, you deserve all the best. I'll try to generate everything here without the plugin and update you on the matter. Thanks again.

Comment: You are right. The plugin is the cause of the issue, I used the example generator on jOOQ website and the `ExpressaoRecord` was generated correctly, sorry to take your time. Thanks a LOT for helping me with this.